# heap corruption compilando um projeto do opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, opencv

```
void trackFilteredObject(int &x, int &y, Mat threshold, Mat &cameraFeed) {
Mat temp;
threshold.copyTo(temp);
//these two vectors needed for output of findContours
vector< vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
//find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function
findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
//use moments method to find our filtered object
double refArea = 0;
int largestIndex = 0;
bool objectFound = false;
if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {
    int numObjects = hierarchy.size();
    //if number of objects greater than MAX_NUM_OBJECTS we have a noisy filter
    if (numObjects<MAX_NUM_OBJECTS) {
        for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

            Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
            double area = moment.m00;

            //if the area is less than 20 px by 20px then it is probably just noise
            //if the area is the same as the 3/2 of the image size, probably just a bad filter
            //we only want the object with the largest area so we save a reference area each
            //iteration and compare it to the area in the next iteration.
            if (area>MIN_OBJECT_AREA && area<MAX_OBJECT_AREA && area>refArea) {
                x = moment.m10 / area;
                y = moment.m01 / area;
                objectFound = true;
                refArea = area;
                //save index of largest contour to use with drawContours
                largestIndex = index;
            }
            else objectFound = false;


        }
        //let user know you found an object
        if (objectFound == true) {
            putText(cameraFeed, "Tracking Object", Point(0, 50), 2, 1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            //draw object location on screen
            drawObject(x, y, cameraFeed);
            //draw largest contour
            //drawContours(cameraFeed, contours, largestIndex, Scalar(0, 255, 255), 2);
        }

    }
    else putText(cameraFeed, "TOO MUCH NOISE! ADJUST FILTER", Point(0, 50), 1, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
}
```

sempre que eu compilo meu codigo com essa funçao, aparece esse problema, heap corruption. eu quero rastrear um objeto e desenhar uma figura geometrica nele

Então, esse erro aparece em tempo de execução, somente quando uso essa função. depurando o código, o erro ocorre no momento em que saio da função. Pelo que vi, esta ocorrendo algo com a utilização dos vetores que uso como parâmetro...

Comment: O erro ocorreu em tempo de execução ou compilação? Quando você depura, em que linha do código o erro aparece? Se é só quando vc usa essa função, está ligado à dependência do OpenCV ou à função em si? Quero dizer, o seu código já funciona com outras coisas do OpenCV? Mais uma coisa: vc está usando as bibliotecas do OpenCV compiladas para o VS 2015 e para a plataforma correta (32 bit x 64 bit)? Por favor, edite a pergunta para informar esses detalhes.

Comment: Então, esse erro aparece em tempo de execução, somente quando uso essa função. depurando o código, o erro ocorre no momento em que saio da função. Pelo que vi, esta ocorrendo algo com a utilização dos vetores que uso como parâmetro... Consegui rodar outras coisas com a biblioteca sem problemas, apenas com essa função findCountors encontro esse tipo de problema. pior que ele é de grande ajuda para a aplicação que estou querendo. e antes que esqueça, obrigado Luiz Vieira

Comment: Bom, eu fiz um teste aqui no meu ambiente (da forma que eu pude, já que o seu código não compila pela falta de muita coisa - constantes, outra função, definição de qual é o threshold utilizado, etc), e não gerou o mesmo erro. Eu insisto que pode ser algum problema com a sua compilação do OpenCV.

Comment: Se você preparar um exemplo mínimo e completo que seja facilmente compilado em um projeto separado, eu testo aqui novamente. Mas acho que vai funcionar também. Vc chegou a testar no seu ambiente o exemplo do OpenCV? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html